# Notes attributes syntax changed? - Notes attributes via API call fails for me

Tags: shopify

Hello Shopfiy Developers!

I'm having an issue with the notes attributes via API call. It used to work up until a month ago and then things start to go sideways. Has any syntax changed? Here is a snippet of my code that returns an error in the for loop.

Error message "Undefined index: note_attribute right at the foreach line"

```
// Overwrite custom status field if it's defined in note-attributes
if(array_key_exists('note-attributes', $o))
{
    // For whatever reason, the note-attributes are formatted
    // differently if there's only one key => value pair
    // ( * see examples at end of this file )
    // If the note-attribute array has the key 'name' in it, it's just a single pair.
    // Otherwise, the note-attribute array would be numerically indexed with keys 0,1,2.. etc
    if(array_key_exists('name',$o['note-attributes']['note_attribute']))
    {
        if($o['note-attributes']['note_attribute']['name'] == "custom_status")
            $arr_tmp[7] = $o['note-attributes']['note_attribute']['value'] ;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($o['note-attributes']['note_attribute'] as $na) //Fails here
        {
            if($na['name'] == "custom_status")
                $arr_tmp[7] = $na['value'] ;
        }
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think posting the error message might help.

Comment: Error message "Undefined index: note_attribute right at the foreach line"

Comment: So `$o['note-attributes']` doesn't have an element `note_attribute`. But if that's the case I would think the `array_key_exists` check in the if should raise the same error...

Comment: You are correct. My db logs were backed up. array_key_exists fails as well "An Error occurred: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given" I believe that $o has correct data in it b/c I correctly pull $o['billing-address'] and several other order values just above this statement.

Comment: RESOLVED. Confirmed bug from shopify. The reason we had issues is that we noticed the bug weeks ago and simplly update our syntax, when they switched it back it broke again. All is well now.  More info: 

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shopify-app-discuss/dJ97gLNEGAs

Comment: Ryan, please mark Edward's answer below as accepted so that it's obvious that the issue is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was due to a change in XML node syntax; Shopify had a regression that changed `note-attributes` to `note_attributes` in the response and it was changed back.